# How to pass an image with props in vuejs without all the content disappearing when there's no image?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a component that in some cases will receive an image and in others it won't. So, I want this component to work in both ways. But, when it doesn't have any image, the other contents of this component, including styles doesn't work, they disappear. Is there a way that I can do this?

App.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="raleway">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <section class="title">
      <Title name='Title' filename="twitter"/>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Title from "./components/Title.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Title,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #3B3B3B;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}

.title{
  margin-top: 8em;
}
</style>
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="background">
      <div class="title">
        <h2><img :src="require(`@/assets/${filename}.svg`)" class="img">{{name}}</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Background',
  props:{
      name: String,
      filename: String,
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.background{
    background-color: #3B3B3B;
}
.title{
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

.title h2{
    text-align: left;
    color: #B16DFF;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.img{
  padding-right: 1em;
}

@media(max-width: 580px){
  .title h2{
      font-size: 1.17em;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) to conditionally render the `<img>` based on whether `filename` is truthy:

```html
<img v-if="filename" :src="require(`@/assets/${filename}.svg`)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pass in the image reference as a computed property, not requiring it directly in the source.

Then in the template you could use `v-if` to check if that was present, and render a 'no image' message using `v-else` if no image data present